# How to find the direction vector of a ball falling off an ellipsoid?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, partial-derivative

> A tiny ball is placed in top of an ellipsoid $3x^2+2y^2+z^2=9$ at $(1,1,2)$. Find the three-dimensional vector $\underline u$ in whose direction the ball will start moving after the ball is released.

I feel this problem involves usage of gradients but not sure how to tackle it.

**EDIT** the solution shouldn't use physics knowledge and has to be based on directional derivatives and/or gradients.

**EDIT** **1** I've finally come up with the "no physics solution" however it is different from the accepted answer, I'd appreciate if other members confirm if the accepted answer is correct.

One potential flaw with the accepted answer is that it's not using the $9$ from the original equation $3x^2+2y^2+z^2+\mathbf{9}=0$.

Anyway this is my take:

The $xy$ direction in which the ball will fall is $-\nabla f(1,1)$.

$f_x=-\frac{3x}{\sqrt{9-3x^2-2y^2}}\stackrel{we.plug.in.x=1}{=}-\frac{3}{2}$.

Similarly, $f_y=-1$ therefore $-\nabla f(1,1)=\langle 3/2,1 \rangle$.

Let the 3d vector we're after be $d=\langle 3/2, 1, a \rangle$. Notice that $d$ is perpendicular to the normal vector of the tangential plane $n=\langle 6x,4x,-1 \rangle=\langle 6,4,-1 \rangle$ so $d\cdot n=0$ therefore $a=13$ so the final result is $d=\langle \frac{3}{2}, 1,13\rangle$.

Comment: If the gradient is the direction of fastest ascent, then its negative is that of steepest descent. The intuition is that when a ball is dropped, it will follow the path that goes down the fastest. So the answer is $-\Delta f$

Comment: A ball resting on an ellipsoid in the field of gravity IS physics. There's no way that you can solve the problem without physics, no matter what your professor tells you. You professor wants you to solve this problem by intuition. Intuition certainly helps but it's not science. And don't use problems from physics is usage of physics is prohibited.

Comment: @Oldboy I believe the problem can be solved by calculating $-\nabla f(1,1,2)|$ without any physics involved, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are wrong! How do you know if the ball will move up or down without physics? Without physics I can state that the ball will move in the direction of New York and I can also invent a NY operator to state that.

Comment: I think it's quite obvious that ball will be moving downwards so we're interested in the direction if steepest descent which is given by $-\nabla f$. I will accept your answer even though I don't have the necessary physics background to actually understand.

Comment: Basically you are saying that the ball will move in the direction of the steepest descent which is perfectly true. But that's not mathematics! That's just physics that you are taking for granted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that z-axis is oriented vertical upwards.

$f(x,y,z) = 3x^2+2y^2+z^2 - 9 = 0$

Vector $\vec{N}$ perpendicular to the surface $f$ at point $(x,y,z)$ is defined by function gradient:

$\vec{N} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \vec{i} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \vec{j} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \vec{k} = 6 x \vec{i} + 4y \vec{j}+2z \vec{k}$

At point $(1,1,2)$:

$\vec{N} = 6 \vec{i} + 4 \vec{j} + 4 \vec{k} $

Unit vector corresponding to acceleration of Earth's gravity is:

$\vec{G} = - \vec{k}$

Calculate cross product of vectors $\vec{N}$ and $\vec{G}$. That vector is perpendicular to both vectors and also tangential to the surface:

$\vec{T} = \vec{G} \times \vec{N} = -\vec{k} \times (6 \vec{i} + 4 \vec{j} + 4 \vec{k}) = 4 \vec{i} - 6 \vec{j}$

Calculate vector $\vec{P}$:

$ \vec{P} = \vec{N} \times \vec{T} = (6 \vec{i} + 4 \vec{j} + 4 \vec{k}) \times (4 \vec{i} - 6 \vec{j}) = 24 \vec{i} + 16 \vec{j} - 52 \vec{k}$

This vector is also tangential to the surface $f$ and lies in the plane defined by vectors $\vec{G}$ and $\vec{N}$ and therefore describes the direction of ball motion. You can normalize this vector if necessary.

Comment: I know that the solution to this problem should not include physics. While it is definitely an interesting example the problem should be solved without knowledge of gravity

Comment: If you exclude physics and gravity completely, the ball just won't move.

Comment: For the sake of the problem we can assume it will move. It's a problem from my calculus course not physics

Comment: I mean, direction of ball movement is determined by physics *and* math, math alone can give you nothing.

Comment: I agree but the teacher stressed that no knowledge of physics is required to solve the problem. What is needed is knowledge of directional derivatives and gradients

Comment: Your teacher probabably means that you need very basic physics here, but you cannot get rid of it completely. Basic physics: the ball will move tangential to the surface in a plane defined by vectors $\vec{G}$ and $\vec{N}$. You cannot solve the problem without this.

Comment: In the calculation of $P$ you meant $P=N \times T$?

Comment: Just upvoted your answer to cancel the downvote. Your answer is the correct one, I don't know why the OP insists not to use any physics.

Comment: @ Taozi because we were told the solution only involves gradients and directional derivative. While the answer may be correct it's not what I should be using for my answer

Comment: @Yos: You have downvoted my perfectly correct answer because you did not like my use of physics. But your original problem statement DID NOT MENTION that use of physics was prohibited. You have edited your problem statement AFTER my answer was posted. That's simply UNFAIR!

Comment: I did not downvote your answer

Comment: @Oldboy shouldn't you be using the $9$ from the original equation $3x^2+2y^2+z^2+\mathbf 9=0$?

Comment: Either there's something wrong with my answer or yours but this is my version: the $xy$ direction in which the ball will fall is $-\nabla f(1,1)$. $f_x=-\frac{3x}{\sqrt{9-3x^2-2y^2}}\stackrel{we.plug.in.x=1}{=}-\frac{3}{2}$. Similarly, $f_y=-1$ therefore $-\nabla f(1,1)=\langle 3/2,1 \rangle$. Let the 3d vector we're after be $d=\langle 3/2, 1, a \rangle$. Notice that $d$ is perpendicular to the normal vector of the tangential plane $n$ so $dn=0$ therefore $a=-13/4$ so the final result is $d=\langle 3/2, 1,-13/4\rangle$. While the $z$ coordinate is a multiple of your $z$ the others are not.

Answer (score 1):

Another derivation (besides the answer by Oldboy) is to decompose the gravity vector into the normal (to surface) and parallel (to surface) components.

The normal component is $(\vec{G}\cdot \vec{n})\cdot \vec{n}$, the parallel component is $\vec{G}-(\vec{G}\cdot \vec{n})\cdot \vec{n}$. The parallel direction is the falling direction (same as Oldboy's answer).

Comment: Actually, I like your solution even more :)