# How to find the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ which goes through $(3,1)$ and has the minimal area?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> How to find the ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ which goes through $(3,1)$ and has the minimal area? Ellipse area is given as $\pi ab$.

My approach is to use Lagrange method where the constraint function $g=\pi ab$ while the minimization function $f=\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-1=\frac{3^2}{a^2}+\frac{1^2}{b^2}=1$ to account for the given point.

We can then calculate $b=\pm\sqrt 2$ and $a=\pm \sqrt{18}$.

Area can't be negative so we have that the minimal values of $g$ will occur at $(\sqrt 2, \sqrt{18})$ and $(-\sqrt 2, -\sqrt{18})$.

As far as I understand Lagrange multipliers gives us just the stationary points. In order to check that they really are min values we can use the second derivatives test:
$$
g_{aa}=0, g_{bb}=0, g_{ab}=\pi
$$
Then:
$$
D=g_{aa}\cdot g_{bb}-g^2_{ab}=-\pi^2<0
$$

But in order to have a min point I need $g_{aa}>0$ while it's exactly $0$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, the function you seek to minimize is $f=\pi ab$ subject to $g=\frac9{a^2}+\frac1{b^2}=1$, ie, you seek to minimize the area $f$ under the condition $g$ that the ellipse contains the point $(3,1)$.

So you've got the minimization and restriction backwards.

Comment: In general though we do need to check if the points we get from Lagrange multipliers are indeed min/max values right?

Comment: Yes! Lagrange multipliers only gives us the critical points of the Lagrangian, but they do not necessarily correspond to global extrema; indeed, they need not even be local extrema. There is an analogy here with how setting $f'(x)=0$ does not guarantee that $x$ is a global/local extremum -- think inflection or saddle points.

Comment: What puzzles me is that neither in the textbooks nor in other examples I see no one bothers to check this

Comment: If it's interesting for you there's a question I posted but still has no answer (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287640/how-to-find-the-direction-vector-of-a-ball-falling-off-an-ellipsoid) I need to use gradients in that answer so I think $\nabla f$ is the answer.

Comment: If you know beforehand that an extremum must exist (say, because the domain is compact) and you find a finite number of points via Lagrange multipliers, you can directly compute their values to determine which is the maximum. This is often easier than doing second-derivative or Hessian checks.

Comment: Also, on the linked question, check the comment by Fede Poncio on the question. He used the inverted gradient symbol, but the reasoning is sound.

Comment: So the answer is $-||\nabla f||$?

Comment: For that particular question, $-\nabla f(1,1,2)$. No need for the norm.

Answer (score 1):

We have the general equation of an ellipse:
$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 $$
whose area is:
$$ f(a,b) = \pi a b$$

We want to minimize the area $f(a,b)$ subject to the constraint that the ellipse passes through the point $(3,1)$, that is:
$$ g(a,b) = \frac{9}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} = 1 $$

Applying the method of Lagrange multipliers, and noting that both $a$ and $b$ are nonzero and we only care about positive $a,b$, we get that the contrained extrema occur at:
\begin{align*}
\nabla f(a,b) &= \lambda \cdot \nabla g(a,b) \\
g(a,b) &=1 \\[15pt]
\pi b &= -\lambda \frac{18}{a^3} \\
\pi a &= -\lambda \frac{2}{b^3} \\
\frac{9}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} &=1 \\[15pt]
a^3 b &= 9ab^3  \\
\frac{9}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} &=1 \\[15pt]
a^2 &= 9b^2  \\
\frac{9}{a^2} + \frac{1}{b^2} &=1 \\[15pt]
a &= 3b  \\
\frac{2}{b^2} &=1 \\[15pt]
\end{align*}

> \begin{align*} a &= 3\sqrt{2}  \\ b &= \sqrt{2} \end{align*}

This choice of $(a,b)$ gives the ellipse area

> $$A = 6\pi$$

We know this must be the minimum, since the choice of $(a,b) = (6,2/\sqrt{3})$ satisfies the constraint, yet gives a greater ellipse area since $2/\sqrt{3} > 1$

Comment: How did you get $(6,2\sqrt 3)$?

Comment: Its just a point that satisfies the constraint, so its one possible choice of ellipse that has greater area.

Comment: It's just a random multiple of $(a,b)$?

Comment: This is not a multiple of the minimum solution. A multiple of the minimum solution wouldn't satisfy the constraint. This is just a point that satisfies the constraint, but corresponds to a larger area that the optimal solution, meaning the optimal solution cannot be a maximum, so it has to be a minimum.

Comment: I'm confused: why do we need to show that there exists another possible solution if already found a stationary point? if there were other stationary points we would've found them right?

Comment: @Yos How do you know that this stationary point corresponds to a minimum?

Comment: @ amd I'm using the second derivative test on the stationary point in order to determine that it's a min

Comment: You are looking at all solutions to the constrained equation, and the method of lagrange multipliers finds the extrema. If there is only one extrema, and you show that there is a solution that correponds to a larger value, then the extrema has to be a minimum.